# Form_open in codeigniter not working

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter-3

I've made a simple project in which a user can register his account, login with his credentials, view his blog posts and create a new blog. I'm currently working on creating a new blog which is simple a form with two options: blog title and content. I'm stuck with the part where you hit submit and the form is passed to the controller specified in form_open function. Nothing is happening when I hit the submit button, this is the issue.

Here is my view file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Enter your Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <?=form_open("blog/submitpost"); ?>
                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="blogtitle" class="control-label col-sm-2">Blog Title</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="text" name="blogtitle" placeholder="Enter your title here" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="blogdesc" class="control-label col-sm-2">Blog Title</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <textarea name="blogdesc" rows="8" cols="40" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your post here"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?=form_close();?>
            <div style="text-align: center;">
                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Blog extends CI_Controller{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('user');
        $this->load->helper('form');
    }


    public function new_post($id){
        $data['id'] = $id;
        $this->load->view('blog_new_post',$data);
    }

    public function blogpostview($id){
        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
        $data['id'] = $id;
        $data['posts'] = $this->user->blog_post_list($data['username']);
        $this->load->view('blog_view',$data);
    }

    public function submitpost(){
      //there will be additional code here
        $this->load->view('blog_post_view');
    }

}
?>
```

Now firstly, I'm aware one has to load the Form helper class to achieve this, which I've already done. I've even changed the autoload.php file to automatically load it.

Secondly, I've already implemented this twice during registration and login processes. This time however I don't know why the code isn't working.

Comment: <?php echo form_open("blog/submitpost"); ?>  instead of  <?=form_open("blog/submitpost"); ?>

Comment: Because ,Some time php short tag not allowed.. Can you please check short_open_tag in  php.ini configuration file ?

Comment: Use,
<?php echo form_open("blog/submitpost"); ?>
<?php echo form_close();?>
because of short open tags problem.
thanks.

Comment: It originally was <?php echo form_open("blog/submitpost"); ?> after which I changed it to codeigniter's format. It's not working as well.

Comment: Nope. I just checked. No changes. haha the suspense is killing me!

Comment: Kindly add this in constructor,
$this->load->helper('url');

Comment: Not working. And it's already getting loaded in autoload.php

Comment: can u show me routes.php file?

Comment: Thank you guys for your help but I found my mistake. I had not placed the submit button inside the form. I did so and it worked right away.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got the solution and it's a very simple one. I had not placed the submit button in the form due to which the problem was coming! Sometimes it's the simplest solutions that work out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Enter your Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <?php echo form_open("blog/submitpost"); ?>
                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="blogtitle" class="control-label col-sm-2">Blog Title</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="text" name="blogtitle" placeholder="Enter your title here" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="blogdesc" class="control-label col-sm-2">Blog Title</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <textarea name="blogdesc" rows="8" cols="40" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your post here"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div style="text-align: center;">
                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
            </div>
            <?=form_close();?>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php 
 $attributes = array('name' => 'add_blog','id' => 'add_blog', 'method' =>'POST')
 echo form_open("blog/submitpost", $attributes); ?> //form open


    <?php echo form_close(); ?> //form close
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.....

```
    <?php 


     $data = array('action' =>'blog/submitpost','id' => 'add_blog', 'method' =>'POST', )
     echo form_open("blog/submitpost", $data); ?> 
    <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="blogtitle" class="control-label col-sm-2">Blog Title</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="text" name="blogtitle" placeholder="Enter your title here" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="blogdesc" class="control-label col-sm-2">Blog Title</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <textarea name="blogdesc" rows="8" cols="40" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your post here"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div style="text-align: center;">
                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
            </div>
 <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```